# aws s3 response headers

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a custom header in the ObjectMetadata class and have the following code for it

```
private String cust_header;
public String getcust_header() {
    return cust_header;
}

public void setcust_header(String cust_header) {
    cust_header = cust_header;
}
```

This is how the constructor looks :

```
private ObjectMetadata(ObjectMetadata from) {
    this.userMetadata = from.userMetadata == null
        ? null
        : new TreeMap<String,String>(from.userMetadata);
    // shallow clone the meata data
    this.metadata = from.metadata == null
        ? null
        : new TreeMap<String, Object>(from.metadata);
    this.expirationTime = cloneDate(from.expirationTime);
    this.expirationTimeRuleId = from.expirationTimeRuleId;
    this.httpExpiresDate = cloneDate(from.httpExpiresDate);
    this.ongoingRestore = from.ongoingRestore;
    this.restoreExpirationTime = cloneDate(from.restoreExpirationTime);
    this.cust_header = "custom header";
}
```

I am trying to upload a file to an s3 instance and get the response header. Below is my code:

```
AmazonS3 conn = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).build();
    Bucket bucket;
    if (conn.doesBucketExist("xxx")) {
        System.out.println("Bucket already exists");

    }
    bucket = conn.createBucket("xxx");

    ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello World!".getBytes());
    ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucket.getName(), "hello.txt", input, objectMetadata);

    PutObjectResult response = conn.putObject(request);

    S3Object object = conn.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket.getName(), "hello.txt"));
    InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
    System.out.println("Content-Type: " + object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType() + " custom Header : "
            + object.getObjectMetadata().getcust_header());
```

I am trying to print all the headers.
However I am getting null values while trying to print all headers. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Source [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arrived at a solution which is working fine. The custom headers which would be read by the response will have to be set unlike the HTTP headers. Then we can print like below:

```
Date expirationTime = new Date();
response.setETag("123");
response.setExpirationTime(expirationTime);
System.out.println("ET Flag : " + response.getETag() + " " + "Expiration Time" + response.getExpirationTime() + " ");
```

First we have to create the custom header in `ObjectMetadata` and then
we have to use the methods provided in the `PutObjectRequest` or create custom getters and setters for custom objects.